# JSON to a HTML Table

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Well i still haven't solved this. Been at it for a couple of days now. What i have done already is: I have written a php script which echos my JSON data structure. I am now trying to write a Html script which will obtain the results in JSON format but echo this out in a html table. I coded my html page, however for some reason the table isn't showing up.

Ok what my json_encode($res->fetchAll()) echo looks like is this;

```
[{"name":"Victoria
```

Comment: When i click on the submit button nothing happens.

Comment: Your question in it's current form makes no sense at all. The answer looks totally unrelated. Please keep it usable for future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your out is not valid json, the `echo "{$res->numRows()}<br/>";` invalidates it and needs to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Use [data tables](http://www.datatables.net/) . It is very powerful and easy to use java script api. It provides a lot of features as well like sorting searching etc.

You only have to change the format of JSON and rest all will be taken care by datatables.

An [example](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)